# How parse json recursively using codable with swift

Tags: swift, recursion, codable

I am trying to defining a decoding class model to decode this kind of json file:
Here a short extraction to understand the problem, in reality it is more nested.

```
{
    "Title" : "Root",
    "Subtitle" : "RootTree",
    "Launch" : [
        {
            "DisplayName" : "Clients",
            "Launch" : [
                {
                    "DisplayName" : "Clients Details",
                    "Launch" : [
                        {
                            "DisplayName" : "Item1",
                            "URI" : "/rest/..."
                        },
                        {
                            "DisplayName" : "Item2",
                            "URI" : "/rest/..."
                        },
                        {
                            "DisplayName" : "Item3",
                            "URI" : "/rest/..."
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Here my structure, I used a class because of the recursive usage:

```swift
final class Url: Codable {
    let name : String
    let uri: String?
    let launch: [LaunchStructure]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "DisplayName"
        case uri = "URI"
        case launch = "Launch"
    }
}
final class LaunchStructure: Codable {
    let launch: [Url]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case launch = "Launch"
    }
}
```

In the Title and Subtitle I am not interested, therefore I have excluded it from the class. I would like to get the Displayname and the uri from the items. As I said, the structure is more nested, but always the same structure. Is it possible to read the elements using a recursive way.
I am to decode it in this manner:

```
...
let result  = Result { try JSONDecoder().decode(LaunchStructure.self, from: data) }
```

Thank you, best regards
Arnold

Comment: check this out: https://learnappmaking.com/codable-json-swift-how-to/

Comment: @Arnold I think the code that you've provided working for `Decoding`, isn't it?

Comment: @Bohdan Why, isn't it? I tried this code without success. I tried it also usin [LaunchStructure.self] but without success. What is wrong about my class? If possible I would like to parse the json with two classes or max three, therefore the recursive approach. Perhaps you can give me a hint.

Comment: *the structure is ... always the same structure*. Actually it's not. The outmost dictionary doesn't have an `URI` and `DisplayName` key, the middle dictionary doesn't have an `URI` key and and the inner dictionary doesn't have a `launch` key.

Comment: @vadian yes you are right. but I mean therefore I have optionals. But we have always a array with the name launch and in this array elements with a name and other arrays and in the last step an item with name and an uri. But you are right, not indeed the same structure, but a repeating one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need two types here at all, just one will do:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let name : String? // not all entries in your example has it, so it's optional
    let uri: String?
    let launch: [Item]? // same here, all leaf items doesn't have it

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "DisplayName"
        case uri = "URI"
        case launch = "Launch"
    }
}
```